Simulating the passing of time in forge test for a timelocked contract?
Context
I wrote a contract that aims to raise uint256 investmentTarget funds, within a time period of uint32 private _raisePeriod; after the constructor has been initialised at _startTime = block.timestamp;. If the uint256 investmentTarget is not reached within that period, it should return all received investments.
So I give that contract the modifier:
modifier onlyAfterDelayAndUnderTarget() {
    console2.log("_startTime=",_startTime);
    console2.log("_raisePeriod=",_raisePeriod);
    console2.log("_cumReceivedInvestments=",_cumReceivedInvestments);
    console2.log("_investmentTarget=",_investmentTarget);
    require(block.timestamp >= _startTime + _raisePeriod, "5 weeks haven't passed yet");
    require(_cumReceivedInvestments < _investmentTarget, "Investment target reached");
    _; // Allows execution of the decorated (triggerReturnAll) function.
  }


and that modifier is applied to the return function:
  function _triggerReturnAll() internal onlyAfterDelayAndUnderTarget {
    // TODO: return all investments.
    uint256 nrOfTierInvestments = _tierInvestments.length;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < nrOfTierInvestments; ++i) {
      // Transfer the amount to the PaymentSplitter contract
      payable(_tierInvestments[i].getInvestor()).transfer(_tierInvestments[i].getNewInvestmentAmount());
    }
    require(address(this).balance == 0, "After returning investments, there is still money in the contract.");
  }

and the contract is constructed & tested with:
function testRaisePeriodReturnSingleInvestment() public virtual override {
      console2.log("block.timestamp=",block.timestamp);

      // Simulate 3 weeks passing by
      vm.warp(block.timestamp+3 weeks);
      console2.log("3 weeks later block.timestamp=",block.timestamp);
      assertEq(address(_dim).balance, 0.5 ether, "The _dim did not contain 0.5 ether.");
      
      
      vm.warp(block.timestamp + 15 weeks);
      console2.log("15 weeks later block.timestamp=",block.timestamp);
      assertEq(address(_dim).balance, 0 ether, "The _dim did not contain 0 ether.");
      
  }

Issue
The test fails at the last assert because the balance is unchanged:
0595] MultipleInvestmentTest::testRaisePeriodReturnSingleInvestment()
    ├─ [0] VM::warp(1814400 [1.814e6])
    │   └─ ← [Return] 
    ├─ [0] VM::warp(6652800 [6.652e6])
    │   └─ ← [Return] 
    ├─ emit LogNamedString(key: "Error", value: "The _dim did not contain 0 ether.")
    ├─ emit Log(err: "Error: a == b not satisfied [uint256]")
    ├─ emit LogNamedUint256(key: "   Left", value: 500000000000000000 [5e17])
    ├─ emit LogNamedUint256(key: "  Right", value: 0)
    ├─ [0] VM::store(VM: [0x7109709ECfa91a80626fF3989D68f67F5b1DD12D], 0x6661696c65640000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001)
    │   └─ ← [Return] 
    └─ ← [Stop] 

Suite result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 skipped; finished in 801.30µs (38.02µs CPU time)

Ran 1 test suite in 794.98ms (801.30µs CPU time): 0 tests passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped (1 total tests)

Failing tests:
Encountered 1 failing test in test/unit/RaiePeriod.t.sol:MultipleInvestmentTest
[FAIL. Reason: assertion failed] testRaisePeriodReturnSingleInvestment() (gas: 40595)

I think that implies that either I am not testing the passing of time correctly, or, (I consider this more likely), I did not implement the tracking of time and the accompanying investment return trigger correctly in the main contract that is being tested.
Question
How can I ensure the contract (autonomously) triggers a function after n weeks have passed, and test that it has triggered that function, using a forge test?

Invalid Assumptions
In the original question I made 2 invalid assumptions:

The vm.warp(x) function does not warp for a duration of x seconds, but warps to the time x from the time of the first block.
The contract should automatically activate if a certain time is reached.

In this case, someone wants the contract to act, the investors, so 1 of them should call this function to get their money back.
Working Solution
In the main contract I added modifier:
modifier onlyAfterDelayAndUnderTarget() {
    require(block.timestamp >= _startTime + _raisePeriod, "The fund raising period has not passed yet.");
    require(_cumReceivedInvestments < _investmentTarget, "Investment target reached!");
    _; // Allows execution of the decorated (triggerReturnAll) function.
  }

and payout function:
function triggerReturnAll() public onlyAfterDelayAndUnderTarget {
    // TODO: return all investments.
    uint256 nrOfTierInvestments = _tierInvestments.length;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < nrOfTierInvestments; ++i) {
      // Transfer the amount to the PaymentSplitter contract
      payable(_tierInvestments[i].getInvestor()).transfer(_tierInvestments[i].getNewInvestmentAmount());
    }
    require(address(this).balance == 0, "After returning investments, there is still money in the contract.");
  }

and in the test(s) I wrote:
function testRaisePeriodReturnSingleInvestment() public virtual override {
    // Simulate 3 weeks passing by
    vm.warp(block.timestamp + 3 weeks);

    vm.expectRevert(bytes("The fund raising period has not passed yet."));
    _dim._triggerReturnAll();
    assertEq(address(_dim).balance, 0.5 ether, "The _dim did not contain 0.5 ether.");

    vm.warp(block.timestamp + 15 weeks);

    _dim._triggerReturnAll();
    assertEq(address(_dim).balance, 0 ether, "The _dim did not contain 0 ether.");
  }

  function testKeepInvestmentsForSuccesfullRaise() public virtual override {
    // Simulate 3 weeks passing by
    vm.warp(block.timestamp + 3 weeks);

    vm.expectRevert(bytes("The fund raising period has not passed yet."));
    _dim._triggerReturnAll();
    assertEq(address(_dim).balance, 0.5 ether, "The _dim did not contain 0.5 ether.");

    // Set the msg.sender address to that of the _investorWallet0 for the next call.
    vm.prank(address(_investorWallet0));
    // Send investment directly from the investor wallet into the receiveInvestment function.
    _dim.receiveInvestment{ value: 2.5 ether }();

    vm.warp(block.timestamp + 15 weeks);

    vm.expectRevert(bytes("Investment target reached!"));
    _dim._triggerReturnAll();
    assertEq(address(_dim).balance, 3 ether, "The _dim did not contain 0 ether.");
  }

which pass. I hope it saves someone some time.
Room for Improvement
If someone knows how to make the contract itself payout at a certain (block) time, without being called, I would greatly appreciate your solution!
